# Protractor test needs toContain to have two or more strings

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I need to have a protractor test that will test for two possible strings.
I need something like this:

`expect(element(By.css('.class')).getText()).toContain("string A" || "string B")`

Not sure how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `toMatch()`:

```
expect(element(By.css('.class').getText()).toMatch(/(string A|string B)/);
```